# Erlang mysql example

Tags: mysql, erlang

Just wondering if anyone could give a working example of using the erlang-mysql module (http://code.google.com/p/erlang-mysql-driver/).

I am new to erlang and I am trying to replace some old scripts with a few erlang batch processes.  I am able to connect to the DB and even complete a query, but I am not sure how I use the results.  Here is what I currently have:

```
-include("../include/mysql.hrl").
...
mysql:start_link(p1, "IP-ADDRESS", "erlang", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE"),
Result1 = mysql:fetch(p1, <<"SELECT * FROM users">>),
io:format("Result1: ~p~n", [Result1]),
...
```

I also have a prepared statement that I am also using to get just one row (if it exists) and it would be helpful to know how to access the results on that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-mysql-driver/source/browse/trunk/src/mysql.erl#44) of `mysql.erl`:

Your result will be `{data, MySQLRes}`.

`FieldInfo = mysql:get_result_field_info(MysqlRes)`, where `FieldInfo` is a list of `{Table, Field, Length, Name}` tuples.

`AllRows = mysql:get_result_rows(MysqlRes)`, where `AllRows` is a list of lists, each representing a row.

Comment: Thanks,  As an addon to this:
What is the best way to parse the result?  Sometimes it will result in 0 rows or sometimes there will be lots of rows.  In that light if I needed to grab the email address and the name (from the user table, assume structure is [id, email, name]).  Some sample code for that would be really great.

Comment: `[do_sg(Email, Name) || [_,Email,Name] <- AllRows]`. btw if you don't need ID you should not query it.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the count of rows,
then execute:

eg:
RowLen = erlang:length(Row),
if 
    RowLen > 0 ->
        {success};
    true ->
        {failed, "Row is null"}
end.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to use the ODBC module that comes with Erlang/OTP, and running into problems, I recommend the mysql/otp driver. I replaced ODBC with it in just a few hrs and it works fine.

They have good [documentation](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp) so I will not add examples here.