# register data from erlang to table mysql

Tags: mysql, erlang

I have a table in mysql named **person**
this a simple code of insertion of data in the table person

```
$id = "1";
$firstname = "afif";
$lastname = "kaled";
$test = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if ($test) {
        mysql_select_db("basetest", $test);
    }


    $sql = " INSERT INTO `person` SET
            `id` = '" . $id . "',
                         `firstname` = '" . $firstname . "',
            `lastname` = '" . $lastname . "' ";
            

    @mysql_query($sql, $test);
```

I want to modify this function

```
test()->

Id ="11",
Firstname ="afif",
Lastname ="kaled",

%% here I want to register this data in the table person .
```

so the table person will have this data

**11   afif  kaled**

I want to know if is it possible to register data from erlang to table mysql

I have already done an example of transfer data from erlang to txt file with this code :

```
exporttxt()->
    F = fun() -> mnesia:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [],person) end,
    {atomic,L} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    file:write_file("test.txt",[io_lib:format("~p\t~p\t~p~n",[F1,F2,F3]) || 
                     #person{id = F1,firstname = F2,lastname = F3} <- L]).
```

**but now as I already said I want to know is it possible or not to send data from erlang to a table in mysql**

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for a mysql driver for erlang?

Comment: I want to know is it possible or not to send directly same data from erlang to table ( table in mysql)

Comment: i don't want to be unpolite but did you try to google "mysql erlang driver"?

Comment: I didn' ask for the code , I juste want to know if it is possible or not,  if it is possible of corse I will  develop this function

Comment: Of course it is possible.

Comment: @afifkaled you should search online or in stackoverflow before and then ask only if you don't understand something or if you have errors (possibly with a clear dump of the error).

Answer (score 8):

[Of course](https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver) [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060547/erlang-mysql-example).

Try to use a search before asking questions.