# Erlang MySQL Library for ejabberd

Tags: mysql, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have just started playing with ejabberd server for XMPP stuff.
I could setup it up successfully on a VPS using the default Mnesia database.

Now I am trying to configure **ejabberd** to use a mysql database (instead of Mnesia). I am following the [documentation](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc32). I have done everything except install the Erlang MySQL library. Unfortunately, the link they give in the document is broken. The link is: https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/CONTRIBS/Yxa.

By, googling I could fing this [github repo](https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver) that claims to be an extension and enhancement of the driver that is linked on ejabberd documentation.

**I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHAT IS THE RECOMMENDED ERLANG MYSQL LIBRARY (TO WORK WITH EJABBERD).**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060547/erlang-mysql-example

Comment: My question is "ejabberd related". I do not want to learn how to use the library, but where I can find a library to use with the latest version of ejabberd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [here](http://packages.altlinux.org/br/Sisyphus/srpms/erlang-mysql/sources) a supposedly enhanced version of the library. According to the site:

> This MySQL driver for Erlang is based on the Yxa driver obtained  from
>   Process One (at
>   https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/CONTRIBS/Yxa)  It includes
>   several new features such as prepared statements, transactions, binary
>   queries,  type-converted query results, more efficient logging and a
>   new connection pooling mechanism.

I installed erlang tools on my ubuntu instance that allowed me to compile the library.

Comment: I downloaded the files,any idea on how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of forks of emysql driver in the wild b/c of original driver is no longer maintained, but recent news I [heard](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/erlang-programming/0Hp1Wg-uQf4) that it was picked and improved, check this [repo](https://github.com/Eonblast/Emysql)